# Could the credits for a course be revoked if it is discovered that a student had cheated in the course's prerequisite class?

Tags: cheating, bachelor

I am a college student in the US.

Over a year ago, I took a course that moved online because of the pandemic. The course in question is a graduation requirement. The class's lack of exam proctoring made it easy to cheat and so I did. My cheating was never discovered but as time went on, I grew to deeply regret what I did. I've since sworn off cheating ever again. I felt and still feel incredibly guilty about it, so I tried to atone for what I've done by taking what was essentially a more difficult version of the course I cheated in and passed it without resorting to cheating. This course *alone* satisfies the same requirement that the previous course does, but the previous course is its prerequisite. Students who have not satisfied the course's prerequisites would not have been allowed to enroll in it.

My question is, would my credits for this higher level course be revoked if my cheating in its prerequisite course was ever discovered? I believe that the cheating I did in the prerequisite course would have been enough for me to fail it. If the cheating were to be discovered after I graduate, would it be grounds for degree revocation?

Comment: Please ask one question per post.  The second question is a duplicate.  https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/54807/can-a-university-retract-a-degree-for-actions-taken-after-the-degree-is-awarded

Answer (score 3):

Move on (as has everyone else by now who was involved in the course you cheated on). You learned your lesson -- a good one indeed! -- and so it's time to spend your energies on something productive, rather than past events.

Comment: This is good advice but it doesn't answer the question OP asked in any way.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, would my credits for this higher level course be revoked if my cheating in its prerequisite course was ever discovered?

No.

Comment: Just writing 'no' is a little short for an answer. Can you provide a source or an explanation or something like that.

Comment: @quarague More detail is not justified here.